# Bloom filter implementation for billions of categories

Tags: java, hadoop, bloom-filter

I am new to bloom filter concept. Please let me know your thoughts on this. I have 3 types of categories. Each type contains billions of categories.

1. Do I need 3 bloom filter objects or is there any way to manage all the category types in object?
2. I am using Apache hadoop bloom filter implementation i.e `org.apache.hadoop.util.bloom.Filter`. Is there any other implementation better than this?
3. What should be the ideal bit array size to handle billion records?

Comment: It's unclear what kind of operations you are going to perform on your categories set. Do you only insert and check membership? Will you tolerate false positives (when the filter tells you "yes" on the element, which is actually absent). If yes and yes, then the Bloom filter might be a good choice. As for the problem size of order of billions, I'm very doubtful that the Bloom filter will be better than a simple bitset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do I need 3 bloom filter objects: depending on what you want to do (you didn't describe that), yes.
2. Is there any other implementation: sure! Try using [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=bloom+filter+wikipedia&oq=bloom+filter+wikipedia&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.3035j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=java+bloom+filter).
3. Ideal bit array size: it depends on what you want to do. Try reading the [Wikipedia article about Bloom filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). There are formulas to calculate the probability.